# json Unmarshal replaces properties with zero if it's structured in tags

Tags: json, go

Here's struct of unmarshal target:

```
type ParsedObjectType struct{
    Value struct{
        E []struct {
            B bool
            C float32 `json:"coefficient"`
            CE float32
            G int `json:"group"`
            P float32 `json:"period"`
            T int `json:"type"`
        }
    }
}
```

And soucre string looks like this:

```
{"B":false,"C":2.123,"CE":0,"G":1,"P":1000,"T":0}
```

After `json.Unmarshal([]byte(string), ParsedObjectType)` i receive

```
{
    "B": false,
    "coefficient": 0,
    "CE": 0,
    "group": 0,
    "period": 0,
    "type": 0
}
```

with zeros instead of source data in properties

Comment: Sorry, i placed wrong source example. Fixed in question.

Comment: If I did not mistake what json.Unmarshal does, I think the unmarshal result should be contains key from the struct (i.e. what you received should not happens). The json tag specifies the key in the json string, so if your tag is `json:"coefficient"`, the key in the json should be "coefficient"

Comment: So how then better to marshal unmarshaled string with needed tags?

Comment: Your target struct assumes an object called 'Value' within an object. Your input data doesn't have this format. So, naturally, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand in `json` you have compact names, but it should not force you to create cryptic names in structures.

In the code, you should use meaningful names, but in a serialized format you can use synonyms.

Adapted from your example:
playground: https://play.golang.org/p/gbWhV3FfHMr

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type ParsedObjectType struct {
    Value struct {
        Items []struct {
            Coefficient float32 `json:"C"`
            Group       int     `json:"G"`
            Period      float32 `json:"P"`
            TypeValue   int     `json:"T"`
        } `json:"E"`
    }
}

func main() {

    str := `{"Value": {
            "E": [
              {
                "B": false,
                "C": 2.123,
                "CE": 0,
                "G": 1,
                "P": 1000,
                "T": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        }`

    out := &ParsedObjectType{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), out); err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed unmarshal %s", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Constructed: %#v", out)
}
```

Comment: I understand. But there's other problem. After deserializing i put this object to map inside other object. And after that i want to marshal last object. In that case i want to change json keys into readable. That's my problem.

Comment: @СергейПеренец You need to explain that in your question, then. But the answer to that part is: You need two structs, which are the same, except for their json tags.

Comment: @Cергей I don't see why this will not work, check this one: https://play.golang.org/p/C56e7ZrvxNE

Answer (score 1):

You have two big problems:

1. Your tags are completely wrong. Your input contains, for example `"C":2.123`, but your struct tags mean the Unmarshaler is looking for `"coefficient":2.123`, which it will never find. To correct this, set the tags to match your input:

   ```
   type ParsedObjectType struct{
       Value struct{
           E []struct {
               B  bool
               C  float32 `json:"C"`
               CE float32
               G  int     `json:"G"`
               P  float32 `json:"P"`
               T  int     `json:"T"`
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that now your struct fields match your JSON keys exactly, so you could simply eliminate your JSON tags entirely for simplicity, if you wish:

   ```
   type ParsedObjectType struct{
       Value struct{
           E []struct {
               B  bool
               C  float32
               CE float32
               G  int
               P  float32
               T  int
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Your data structure doesn't appear to match your input.  Your input appears to be a single object, but your input expects an object within an object.  To correct this, (assuming the input you provided in your question is complete), get rid of the extra layer in your data structure:

   ```
   type ParsedObjectType struct{
       B  bool
       C  float32
       CE float32
       G  int
       P  float32
       T  int
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse `{"B":false,"C":2.123,"CE":0,"G":1,"P":1000,"T":0}` to

```
{
"B": false,
"coefficient": 0,
"CE": 0,
"group": 0,
"period": 0,
"type": 0
}
```

I think your struct should be declared as

```
struct {
        B bool
        coefficient float32 `json:"C"`
        CE float32
        group int `json:"G"`
        period float32 `json:"P"`
        type int `json:"T"`
    }
```

Comment: 1) This answer doesn't make any sense; and 2) you can't unmarshal values into unexported fields.

Comment: It does make sense, and seems generally correct (although incomplete), if the unexported fields are corrected.